# Error: Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I setup a pubsub function with firebase functions to do some operations every so often in the Firestore. In order to do this I need to make a request to a third party API to get the updated data and then I want to insert that data into the correct collection and document in the Firestore.

```js
const request_promise = require('request-promise')

exports.scheduledFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 2 minutes').onRun((context) => {
    console.log('This will be called every 2 minutes')
    var username = ''
    var password = ''
    var options = {
        url: 'path.to.api.com',
        auth: {
            user: username,
            password: password
        },
        json: true
    }

    request_promise(options)
        .then(function (product) {
            console.log(product.product_id)
            db.collection('products').doc(product.product_id).set(product)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('Document successfully written')
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Error writing product to firestore', error)
                })
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Failed to get product', error)
        })
  });
```

In the code above if I comment out the call to add the data to the Firestore I the correct product_id prints to the console, so I know the request is working but with it left in I get 'Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value'.

Comment: `require('request_promise')` will be `require('request-promise')`

Comment: You need to return a promise that resolves after all the async work is complete.  Right now, you're ignoring the promises returned by `request_promise()` and `db.collection().doc().set()`.  You will need to learn how to work with effectively with JavaScript promises in order to get Cloud Functions to do what you want.

Comment: Also, `request_promise(options).then(..)` to `return request_promise(options).then(..)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything at your execution. A `console.log` isn't treated as a `return`

```
request_promise(options)
        .then(function (product) {
            console.log(product.product_id)
            // add an implicit return here
            return db.collection('products').doc(product.product_id).set(product)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('Document successfully written')
                    // need's to return something here, using a boolean for simplicity
                    return true;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log('Error writing product to firestore', error)
                    // throw will exit the function call
                    throw Error('Error writing product to firestore', error);
                })
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log('Failed to get product', error);
            // throw will exit the function call
            throw Error('Failed to get product', error);
        })
```

Comment: This is still ignoring the promise returned by the call to Firestore.

Comment: @DougStevenson Not sure if that will make a difference but I had edited it with a `return` within the first `then` that gets executed.

Comment: @DougStevenson I was under the impression that the 'then' block was the promise returned by the call to Firestore

Comment: And it also returns yet another promise.  As does catch.  They are all asynchronous.  You can't turn an asynchronous function into a synchronous one.

Comment: I think promise chaining is not taking properly and that's why call sequence is not maintained

Comment: @mralanlee adding the throws and the 'return true' along with Aritra's fixes above fixed my problems, thanks

Answer (score 1):

With proper promise chaining , this looks more clean

```
      rp(options)
        .then((product) =>
        {
            console.log(product.product_id)
            // add an implicit return here
            return db.collection('products').doc(product.product_id).set(product)
        })
        .then(() =>
        {
            console.log('Document successfully written')
            // need's to return something here, using a boolean for simplicity
            return true;
        })
        .catch(function (err) 
        {
        console.log('Failed to get product', error);
        // throw will exit the function call
        throw Error('Failed to get product', error);
        });
```

Also it is not recommended to throw the errors from catch block, catch block are meant to catch errors and handle them and not to throw errors. There are few bits in your code you need to improve but this is not part of this question

Cheers,
Happy Coding